# Split a data.frame, sort and subset from a list of data.frames

Tags: r

I have a large data.frame that looks like this:

```
   Statistic1    fdr1     Value1   Statistic2  fdr2   Value2
       2        0.0001    Signif      1.8      0.001   Signif 
      0.3        0.13       0          5        0.5      0
      1.5        0.01     Signif      0.4      0.009   Signif
```

I would like to split the data frame every 3 columns, for example Statistic1, fdr1 and Value1. Then sort each splitted data.frame by Statistic* column in descending order and take the first 20 row names of each sorted data.frames corresponding to the Signif label in column Value*
of the sorted data.frame.

Desired output

```
>       df1         

>        Statistic1    fdr1     Value1   
>            2        0.0001    Signif            
>           1.5        0.01     Signif     

>        Statistic2    fdr2     Value2
>           1.8        0.001    Signif 
>           0.4        0.009    Signif
```

From each single data.frame I will take the first 20 row names.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the data frame by using `split.default`. Loop over the list and do the required actions. Translating your requirements would give,

```
lapply(split.default(df, gsub('\\D+', '', names(df))), function(i) 
                                                {i <- i[i[3] != 0,];
                                                 i <- i[order(i[1], decreasing = TRUE),]; 
                                                 i[1:20,]})
```

However, note that since your example only has 3 rows, then doing the last condition (`1:20`) will result in `NA` rows

Answer (score 1):

Here another base solution, based on [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189799/split-dataframe-every-two-columns-into-multiple-dataframe), it's going to split the dataset each three columns, without seeing the names:

```
lapply(seq(1, ncol(df), by=3), function(i) {
                                           i <- df[i: pmin((i+2), ncol(df))]
                                           i <- i[order(i[1], decreasing = TRUE),]
                                           head(i,2)  # put 2 to see the results, you need 20
                                           })

[[1]]
  Statistic1  fdr1 Value1
1        2.0 0.001 Signif
3        1.5 0.010 Signif

[[2]]
  Statistic2  fdr2 Value2
2        5.0 0.500      0
1        1.8 0.001 Signif
```

---

With fake data:

```
df <- data.frame(Statistic1  = c(2, 0.3, 1.5),
                 fdr1 = c(0.001, 0.13, 0.01),
                 Value1 = c("Signif",0,"Signif"),
                 Statistic2  = c(1.8,5,0.4),
                 fdr2 = c(0.001, 0.5, 0.009),
                 Value2 = c("Signif",0,"Signif"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyverse` answer using base R `split.default` we split every 3 columns, `arrange` according to 1st column, `filter` values from 3rd column and finally select rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

map(split.default(df, gl(ncol(df)/3, 3)), 
    . %>% arrange_at(1) %>% 
          filter_at(3, ~. != 0) %>%
          slice(n() : (n()- 2)))


#$`1`
#  Statistic1   fdr1 Value1
#1        2.0 0.0001 Signif
#2        1.5 0.0100 Signif

#$`2`
#  Statistic2  fdr2 Value2
#1        1.8 0.001 Signif
#2        0.4 0.009 Signif
```

For this example this is selecting only 2 rows, for your real data you can change 2 to 20 to get top 20 rows.